# Wordpress sign up

Tags: php, wordpress

I am an ios developer. I have a wordpress site and am making app of this site.
Is there an easy way to signup user like this signin code:

```
$creds['user_login'] = $creds['ios_userlogin'];
$creds['user_password'] = $creds['ios_userpassword'];
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
```

something like `$user = wp_signUP( $creds, false );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [wp_create_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) to create users.

```
wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
```